# Visual Studio 2008 - How to debug my IIS hosted WCF server project when client test project is set as startup

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7, c#-3.0, wcf-security

I am developing a secure set of service using WCF wsHttpBinding. I had to switch from Cassini to my local IIS due to working with SSL, etc. I have my certificates setup, etc. I can debug fine if I startup my WCF project.

My WCF client is in a test project in the solution. When I set my test project as the startup project, and Debug, Visual Studio doesn't attach to IIS, and I cannot trace the server side, it never attachs to IIS.

The only way I can trace is to first start a new Debug instance of server project, then start my test project. The problem is, once the debug session ends, I have to restart both again.

When I'm in Cassini, I'm just able to set the test project as the startup, and it traces through to the server side automatically. Is there a way to accomplish this with the IIS hosted way?

Is there a setting I need to configure in my test project to tell VS to run the server piece in IIS and attach to it?

Comment: Maybe run your WCF in a different instance of VS and attach it to IIS. This should enable you to have the server debugging running while you do things in the client and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Solution>Properties>Startup Project>Multiple startup projects> up to you
```

Comment: AH, thanks. Actually a shortcut to that is Solution -> Set Startup Projects. Thanks that works fine!

Comment: @mrjoltcola, i don't always know the shortest way to an end but generally get there nonetheless. ;-)